# color up each letter of \LaTeX word

Tags: color, characters

How can I assign the specific color to a letter of the word "LaTex" which is wrote in its fancy form?

I tried to coding this by `\textcolor{red}{\LaTeX}` but in this form, the whole word will be red, while I want to each letter has a different color.

Comment: See a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346959/how-do-i-write-latex-in-latex-with-the-first-letter-bolded/346960#346960

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for your response. But it's not quite what I want. For example, I want to make a "LaTeX" with red L and blue T and green X. Your suggested link is working just for 1 letter.

Comment: The adaption for coloured letters is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definitions of `\TeX`, `\LaTeX` and `\LaTeXe` can be found in `latex.ltx`, so just copy over the definitions and add some `\textcolor{...}{...}` statements for the relevant letters.

The chosen colours are just examples.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter


\def\TeXColored{\textcolor{yellow}{T}\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{\textcolor{green}{E}}\kern-.125em\textcolor{brown}{X}\@}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\CLaTeX}{\textcolor{red}{L}\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              \textcolor{blue}{A}}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeXColored}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\CLaTeXe}{\mbox{\m@th
  \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\fi
  \CLaTeX\kern.15em\textcolor{gray}{2}$_{\color{violet}\textstyle\varepsilon}$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CLaTeX\ or \LaTeX

\CLaTeXe\ or \LaTeXe

Huge:\huge

\CLaTeX\ or \LaTeX

\CLaTeXe\ or \LaTeXe


\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an update with external specification of the colours:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\ALetterColor}{blue}
\newcommand{\LLetterColor}{red}
\newcommand{\ChiLetterColor}{green}
\newcommand{\TwoDigitColor}{gray}
\newcommand{\EpsilonLetterColor}{violet}
\newcommand{\ELetterColor}{brown}
\newcommand{\TLetterColor}{yellow}

\makeatletter



\def\TeXColored{\textcolor{\TLetterColor}{T}\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{\textcolor{\ELetterColor}{E}}\kern-.125em\textcolor{\ChiLetterColor}{X}\@}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\CLaTeX}{\textcolor{\LLetterColor}{L}\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              \textcolor{\ALetterColor}{A}}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeXColored}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\CLaTeXe}{\mbox{\m@th
  \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\fi
  \CLaTeX\kern.15em\textcolor{\TwoDigitColor}{2}$_{\color{\EpsilonLetterColor}\textstyle\varepsilon}$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CLaTeX\ or \LaTeX

\CLaTeXe\ or \LaTeXe

Huge:\huge

\CLaTeX\ or \LaTeX

\CLaTeXe\ or \LaTeXe


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a certain reason why you don’t use `\colorlet{ALetterColor}{blue}` (or `\definecolor…`)? :-)

Comment: @Tobi: I am lazy ...

Comment: that's a good reason ;-)